# Permutations (Making numbers from digits)

Tags: permutations

Using the digits 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, and 8, how many different three-digit numbers can you form if each digit may be repeated any number of times in a number?

---

I have tried to do this question and tried to find the answer, unfortunately all the answers were of the question topics "no repeats in digits."
Please help me!

Comment: What have you tried? Showing your attempts really helps people know how to talk about this problem with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $6$ digits in all and each place of a three-digit number can be filled by $6$ ways. Hence, by multiplication rule; $6×6×6=216$ numbers.